# Azure build pipeline with dependency on private AZ repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have an Angular project in an Azure repo that references another private Azure project/Repo in the packages.json file under dependencies. The project builds fine locally for all developers, but fails in the Azure Pipeline with Authentication failed. What is the correct way to pull code from a private Azure repo into another projects build pipeline?

I changed the access protocol from ssh to https and have done a lot of reading about how to accomplish this. I have read about the personal access tokens, but this doesn't seem like a good solution.

```
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"xxx": "git+https://xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx#master",
"date-fns": "^1.30.1",
```

Note: The error is saying fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/..., which doesn't include the provided username in the dependency url.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer help you use the other project in package.json? Don’t hesitate to let us know your puzzle:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with yours. I also think that using PAT token is not a security way, because it does not expose the token exactly.

If you want to use SSH, you need first sure that the repos you want to install has a package.json at root.

And then, generate a pair of public/private key with the command: `vssh-keygen -t rsa`. After that, you can follow this doc: [Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) to install them into your org.

Clone the repos with SSH, and this will make your client accept the fingerprint expressed by the server. Then, go repos page, get the SSH URI to cloning your repos and add it into the dependencies section of your `package.json` file:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "testproj": "git+ssh://account@ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/{org name}/{project name}/{repos name}"
  }
```

Comment: This answer solved the issue. We created a build user in Azure and used its ssh keys to clone from private git repositories.

Comment: @Mengdi Liang...I was trying to append #branch-name at the end of the above string. It seems that it is not working. Do you have any specific solution for it?