# How to import private Azure repo into a project via HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops

I'd like to include an Azure repo I have as a dependency in a new Azure project. I've tried to find a way to do it like this: `npm install --save 'https://your_token@github.com/user/private-repo.git'` but haven't found anything specifically for Azure. The closest thing I found Azure-wise was Microsoft's 'Azure Artifacts' solution which I'd rather not use if I can avoid it. Does anyone know how/if I can do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57500028/azure-build-pipeline-with-dependency-on-private-az-repo), an engineer provided a solution: You can consider to use SSH. First make sure that the repos you want to install has a package.json at root.

Then, generate a pair of public/private key with the command: `vssh-keygen -t rsa`. After that, you can follow this doc: [Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) to install them into your org.

Clone the repos with SSH, and this will make your client accept the fingerprint expressed by the server. Then, go repos page, get the SSH URI to cloning your repos and add it into the dependencies section of your `package.json` file

```
 "dependencies": {
    "testproj": "git+ssh://account@ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/{org name}/{project name}/{repos name}"
  }
```

Comment: Hi Hugh, sorry I think I wasn't as clear as I should have been in my question. What I meant was I have two repos in my Azure project right now and I'd like to include one as a dependency of the other. With Github I can do this by adding the project url in my `package.json` with a token. The solution you gave looks like it would just import a new repo, not include it as a dependency of my existing repo. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for clarification.I misunderstood your question. I updated the answer, an engineer  provided a solution to a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks Hugh, this looks like exactly what I was looking for

Comment: can't we do it using https method? in same project but using different repos(my user credentials do have access of both the repos), can't we simply do it using https method without PAT?

Comment: @HughLin I am trying to append #branch-name at the end. It seems that it is cloning master branch only. Could you be able to help me out here please?