# How to import private Azure repo into a project via SSH?

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, package.json

Like this question [How to import private Azure repo into a project via HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61895532/8468940) I'm trying import a repository like a dependency inside the package.json in another project.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61906140/8468940 seems to be good but I couldn't make it work.

When I tried this way

```
"commons-js": git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/tiagoaleff/commons-js/commons-js
```

I got the following response:

```
Could not install from "git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3\tiagoaleff\commons-js\commons-js" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

But I have a package.json in my commons-js. I also tried another ways and urls but without success.

I also tried this way:

```
git+ssh://account@ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/tiagoaleff/commons-js/commons-js
```

But after some time I got this error:

```
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

Unfortunately I'm in trial and error mode. I don't know If in the company I can use the pipelines and I don't know have experience with this process.

Maybe this approach isn't enable? Or maybe, is pipeline the only solution?

Thanks you guys for your patience and sorry by my English.