# Azure build pipeline with dependency on private AZ repo with SSH

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Found a solution to use private repo [Azure build pipeline with dependency on private AZ repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57500028/20575202) with help ssh key

I was able to set the ssh for my machine and clone the repo successfully

but how to configure ssh for in Azure pipeline ?

Tried solution from this link [Azure build pipeline with dependency on private AZ repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57500028/20575202) it worked only for local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow below steps to configure your pipeline (YAML) to clone your Git repository from Azure Repos to the agent in Azure Pipelines.

1. If you do not have existing SSH key pair generated, reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#step-1-create-your-ssh-keys) to generate the SSH key pair using the **`ssh-keygen`** command on your local machine.

   [image]
2. After the SSH key pair generated, add the SSH public key to the **User settings** > **SSH Public Keys** page on your Azure DevOps. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#step-2--add-the-public-key-to-azure-devops-servicestfs).

   [image]
3. Attempt cloning your Git repository via SSH on your local machine to ensure the SSH can work as expected.
4. Upload the SSH private key to Secure files in the project on Azure DevOps.

   [image]
5. In Azure Pipelines, you can use the [**Install SSH Key task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops) to download the SSH private key from the Secure files and install it on the agent. After successfully installing the SSH private key, on the subsequent tasks in the same job you can use the SSH to clone the Git repository (for example, `git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/{organization}/{project}/{repositoryName}`).

Below is a sample of the YAML pipeline as reference:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: 'Build'
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
  . . .

  - task: InstallSSHKey@0
    displayName: 'Install SSH Private Key'
    inputs:
      knownHostsEntry: '$(SSHknownHost)'  // The value is the content of 'known_hosts' file.
      sshKeySecureFile: 'id_rsa'
  
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Clone Repository'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo 'Clone Repository via SSH'
        git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/{organization}/{project}/{repositoryName}

  . . .
```